# How to inject dependencies in Aurelia without using ES6 class feature

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, aurelia

How do I inject dependencies when exporting a function instead a class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an `inject` property listing your dependencies to your constructor function:

```js
import {EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

export function Example(eventAggregator) {
  console.log(eventAggregator);
  return {
    message: 'hello world'
  };
}

Example.inject = [EventAggregator];
```

Running example:  https://gist.run/?id=d60c5c7dfbf53e507aae47d6c05b7d36

If you'd like to use the `inject` decorator manually instead of adding the static `inject` property you can write:

```
import {EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';

export function Example(eventAggregator) {
  console.log(eventAggregator);
  return {
    message: 'hello world'
  };
}

inject(EventAggregator)(Example);
```

> note: standard decorator "@" syntax requires using ES6 classes so you may want to modernize.